# JavaScript XML Comment Documentation

Tags: .net, javascript, xml, documentation, comments

I'm building a custom library of composite controls that include their own JavaScript files as web resources.  I've got DocProject running to generate my XML documentation CHMs and it's working great.

However, when I set my solution to "Release" configuration, the runtime is still not extracting the XML comments from the embedded JavaScript files and including them in the generated comments.xml file or the .org reflection file.  Therefore, when I run my DocProject build, the comments I have included in my JavaScript files are excluded making my documentation imperfect.

Any thoughts?  I'd love to be able to include the JavaScript documentation directly in the generated CHM.

I have since looked at AjaxDoc on CodePlex, and haven't had success with it after about 6 hours.  Yes, I've contacted Bertrand LeRoy already (creator of AjaxDoc) and hope to hear something back, though I'm sure he's quite busy.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with javascript or xml, per se, but rather DocProject, which you might want to add in your tags.

Comment: The .XML file being generated by the .NET framework is not exporting the XML comments in the javascript file.

It's not DocProject that's fouling up, it's the fact that my "JAVASCRIPT" file's "XML" "COMMENTS" are not showing up in the "DOCUMENTATION" file generated by ".NET".  Maybe now you'll understand the tagging. :)

Answer (score 0):

A few points that may help you understand what is going on:

The XML doc files are built from comments on compiled source code. Javascript is not compiled.

The only support that Visual Studio has for xml docs on JS is in the JS code editor window for intellisense and code completion. That's it.

AjaxDoc is a rather complex beast that works only on JS that is built using MsAjax and leverages it's typing system.

AjaxDoc cannot build xml files for POJO (plain ole' javascript)

I would not hold my breath for any response from Betrand.

I am currently working on a POJO documentation engine but my job has me busy.  You can see an in-browser on-demand doc building prototype in the /docs directory of [this download](https://stackapps.com/questions/1433/soapi-js2-a-fully-relational-javascript-client-library-for-the-stack-exchange-a)

Sorry the news is not better.